# Is Xcode5 stable?

Tags: xcode, ios7, xcode5

I couldn't readily identify if Xcode 5 is stable release/out of beta, and it's getting about that time no? There's also no indication if Xcode5 is stable release or beta on developer.apple.com

I think it was recently announced iOS7 is officially released in 6 days (Sep 18). It wouldn't surprise me if Xcode5 is official now.

Comment: I really don't know what @far's problem with it is, but  for me it's actually very stable since beta 5. Running on MacBook Pro late 2008 2.4Ghz 8GB RAM and SSD as well as on my iMac late 2012 3.4 GHz 16 GB RAM fusion drive...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan on submitting any new apps or updates in the near future, I recommend you switch ASAP (and live with the inconvenience of any possible instability): Since the GM seed, Apple requires that any apps submitted must support iOS 7, and for that you need to build using XCode 5.

On the other hand, if your next binary submission is still several weeks/months away, no need to hurry.

Answer (score 1):

It hasnt been stable in my experience. Its also very slow and if your computer isn't fast enough xcode will probably crash (and i'm running it on an iMac i7 with 16 gb of ram)

Comment: this article says Xcode5 is official now http://www.tuaw.com/2013/09/10/apple-releases-ios-7-and-xcode-gold-master-builds-to-developers/

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it's officially official https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?ls=1&mt=12